# Node.js not change data first time using promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have this issue whit my code, i have a kind of data i need to get current when the user ask for it, i use promise to get the right data out and thats part working well.

my next issue is first time i ask for the data, its return nothing but, if i click agin for the data its return the right data, so something are wrong here.

my promise function

```
var insert = new Promise(function(fulfill) {
  fulfill('test');
});
```

my export moduls

```
exports.signup = function(db, user_conf) {
    var self = this;

    defineUser(user_conf);
    insert.then(function(result) {
        self.json_response = result;
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });

    return self.json_response;
}
```

my express route function

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {

    var post = req.body;

    json_response = users.signup(req.db, {
        'fullname' : post["account-fullname"],
        'username' : post["account-username"],
        'email' : post["account-email"],
        'password' : post["account-password"],
        'retype-password' : post["account-retype-password"],
        'accept-terms' : post["accept-terms"]
    });

    res.send(json_response);
});
```

what i need its i need the respons from my signup part to know about the user can be created or there are a kind of validations error the user need to know before the user can be created.

Comment: `if i click agin` - there's no evidence that any of the code you posted is on a client that has something to `click`

Comment: however, your `export moduls` is incorrect you are returning `self.json_response;` synchronously, however you are assigning a value to it `asynchronously`

Comment: i have a button there send post request to signup pages, first time try to signup its not return status codes as i want but second time its dos and its create both users. This code its a simplified and its still not working, its return "test" first second time i run the promise part, its not return test first time.

Comment: your `export moduls` is incorrect you are returning `self.json_response;` synchronously, however you are assigning a value to it `asynchronously`

Comment: Its sound right, but how shut i run synchronously for this part of my code?

Comment: you can't turn asynchronous code synchronous - well ... maybe some ES7 stuff can make it look that way, but asynchronous is asynchronous, you need to refactor your code to take into consideration the asynchronous nature of the asynchronous parts of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head - try something like this

```
exports.signup = function(db, user_conf) {
    defineUser(user_conf); // I'm assuming this is synchronous
    return insert.then(function(result) {
        // do something here maybe? if not then you only need to return insert;
        return result; // return a result
    });
}

// if nothing is being done in the then callback above, this can be simplified to

exports.signup = function(db, user_conf) {
    defineUser(user_conf); // I'm assuming this is synchronous
    return insert;
}

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = req.body;
    users.signup(req.db, {
        'fullname' : post["account-fullname"],
        'username' : post["account-username"],
        'email' : post["account-email"],
        'password' : post["account-password"],
        'retype-password' : post["account-retype-password"],
        'accept-terms' : post["accept-terms"]
    }).then(function(json_response) {
        res.send(json_response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thats what go wrong! :) thanks for the big helping here :)